# How to redirect to the login page inside a middle-ware in asp.net core with ChallengeAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, middleware

I was trying to restrict access to the path `/swagger` using custom middle-ware. I'm almost done but one problem that I have is I can't make it redirect to login page path `https://localhost:44386/Identity/Account/Login` instead it redirects to `https://localhost:44386/swagger/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44386%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FLogin` which causes **`localhost redirected you too many times.`**

This is the `Startup.cs` class

```cs
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContextConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("SwaggerPermission", "CanExecute"));
            });

            // Set defaut page
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Home");
                    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
                });

            // Add swagger
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "SolarPeple API", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\nEnter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: 'Bearer 12345abcdef'",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });

                var oasr = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement();
                oasr.Add(new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    },
                    Scheme = "oauth2",
                    Name = "Bearer",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                }, new List<string>());

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(oasr);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                // Enable seeding on Dev
                Seeder.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
            }

            // Initialize log4net
            loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

            // Authenticate when hit swagger page
            app.Map("/swagger", branch =>
            {
                branch.UseSwaggerAuthorization("Admin");
            });

            // Initialize swagger
            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
            });

            // Allow http redirection
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            // Allow wwwroot static files to be accessed
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Allow routing
            app.UseRouting();


            // Enable authentication of pages
            app.UseAuthentication();

            // Enable roles based authentication
            app.UseAuthorization();



            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                // Automatically map razor pages
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

And the middle-ware classes

```cs
public static class SwaggerAuthorizationExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerAuthorization(this IApplicationBuilder builder, string policyName)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<SwaggerAuthorization>(policyName);
        }
    }

    public class SwaggerAuthorization
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly string _policyName;

        public SwaggerAuthorization(RequestDelegate next, string policyName)
        {
            _next = next;
            _policyName = policyName;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
        {
            var authorizeResult = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(context.User, null, _policyName);

            if (!authorizeResult.Succeeded)
            {
                var redirectUrl = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(context.Request.Scheme, context.Request.Host, "/Identity/Account/Login");

                await context.ChallengeAsync(new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = redirectUrl
                });

                return;
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using ASP.NET Core Identity, the default authentication scheme for you is the cookie authentication scheme. That is also where that `/Identity/Account/Login` comes from since that is the path that the cookie authentication scheme redirects you to when the user could not be authenticated.

That exactly is also called authentication *challenge* and the cookie authentication scheme happens to be also the default *challenge* scheme. An authentication challenge is basically something that happens when the identity of the user gets challenged and they get prompted to authenticate. For Identity-based authentication, this means that they need to sign in using their Identity credentials.

So the redirect to `/Identity/Account/Login` *is* the challenge of the cookie authentication scheme. To invoke that from your middleware, you just need to invoke `context.ChallengeAsync()`.

The `AuthenticationProperties` that you pass to the `ChallengeAsync` method are used to configure this challenge. By passing the `RedirectUri`, you are saying where the authentication framework should redirect back *after* the challenge was completed; so basically after the user has signed in.

So by setting the `RedirectUri` to the login URL, you are basically saying: “Log in here, and afterwards get redirected to the login where you log in again”.

Instead, what you want to do is challenge the user to log in and then redirect back to whererever they came from or wherever they actually wanted to go through. The easiest way to do that is to take the request path:

```
await context.ChallengeAsync(new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = context.Request.Path,
});
```

---

Note that if you want to access the user information within your middleware, you will need to make sure that the authentication middleware ran *before* that. So you will have to move the `UseAuthentication()` call further up in the pipeline. Otherwise, the user will always be not authenticated.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. However I still get redirect loops. I guess I have to start over again. I feel like I made a bad design.

Comment: You may want to make sure that you call `UseAuthentication` *before* your custom middleware. Otherwise `context.User` will not be set.